# Voxel Engine Block Placement

Tags: game-engine, game-development, chunks, voxel

so I was basically wondering if there'll a way to turn block coordinates into it's chunk coordinates. Because right now I only have the block placement functionally working in one chunk, which is at chunk coordinates 0,0,0. So I this case for example my block data is stored within a 3D array of bytes with different value representing the specific block IDs, thus so my array size is set to 16,256,16 in every chunk that is in a 80,0,80 region of chunks. Though the big question here on how do I say for example find the block at 15,25,96 and return that block ID only when my array size is 16,256,16 for each chunk, like the players coordinate s go beyond that amount? So hopefully if anyone could explain this problem, it would really help me out, thanks

We'll, on what I tried was that I took the players coordinates than divided by the chunk region coordinates using the bitwise operator ">>" to get the right chunk. After processing with that operation I then took the results divided by the chunk x,z
position, on which I checked every value on whether if it in less than 15 or greater than 0 to see if the block coordinates was right.

In the end it seems like it worked but only for a small region, as well with it lags my game and not to mention that only works two ways.

Comment: From what I understand, you can modulo divide block coordinates by a chunk size. This means that if you have a block placed at 15, 25, 96 (x,y,z) then you do something like that for each coordinate (skipping y since my guess is that one chunk covers whole "game hight":

chunk number: ``(x-(x%16))/16``
block number in that chunk: ``x%16``

Comment: This way you end up with this result: Chunk number [0,0,6] Block number in that chunk [15,25,0]. Let me know if that is what u meant. :)